# get TODAY or TOMORROW or DAYNAME with the momentjs

Tags: javascript, datetime, format, momentjs, angular-moment

how to get the TODAY or TOMORROW or DAYNAME with the momentjs.

```
moment('My date').format("dddd);
```

i know this function will give the DAYNAME, but for getting today and tomorrow, what twik we can pass.

Comment: please explain the -1 vote

Comment: I don't think there is any reason for the down vote, I'll up-vote to counter.  I think down-voting, especially when not giving a reason it not really helpful, and SO advises to give a reason, so if it's SO veterans, they should know better.

Answer (score 2):

For tomorrow try ->

```
moment().add(1,'day').format('dddd')
```

edit: If it's the wording tomorrow / yesterday etc. like @this.lau_ mentioned before deleting his message.

```
moment().add(1,'day').calendar()
```

Comment: @this.lau_,  you might have interpreted his question better than me.  so indeed .calendar(), might be what he is after..